# Change NGINX Version installed in Kubernetes cluster or ensure specific version is installed

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm installing nginx using these commands onto my AKS cluster by doing:

kubectl create namespace hello-world

helm3 repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

helm3 install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace hello-world

I want to specify a specifc version of nginx-ingress to be installed onto my namespace
I can see the version when I run "kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-6d4456f967-abc2fb -n hello-world -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version"

How would I be able to update it or configure it next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the available versions using

```
helm search repo nginx -l
```

Install a specific version using

```
helm3 install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace hello-world --version [theVersion]
```